# How to show keyboard on a webview when input is focused at page first load

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

We have a page with a single text input and this page is rendered into an app by a webview. We are using ReactJs.

Simple as it:

```html
<input type="text" ref={input} autoFocus={true} ></input>
```

There is a rule: `The text input need to be selected and the keyboard visible`, to increase user experience (so user don't need to click on text input to open the keyboard).

**IMPORTANT:** This page is the very first one, no user interaction before it!

So, the keyboard don't appear when user loads the page, but *if there are* some interaction, the keyboard appears.

We saw some saying that browsers don't allow you to do it, you are going to need some interaction before.

So, there is a way to achieve it? If not, there is some place that we can read about this 'problem', like: Chrome don't allow you to show keyboard before user interaction?

We've tried to focus, click it programmatically, even with a timeout, but with no luck.

```js
setTimeout(() => {input.current.focus();input.current.click();}, 4000);
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Are you able to get a ***running*** demo up in codesandbox that reproduces issue?